# Stop clearing the text box when the form is submitted

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

I'm creating an ASP.NET web application using MVC 4. In the view, there is a form that contains a text box to browse a file, drop down list box and the submit button. once the form is submitted, the output will be displayed in the text area which resides outside the form.
My problem is, when the form is submitted, only the text box (used to browse the file) will be cleared, but the list box remains with the selected value. And the output will be displayed in the text area.

Following is the code:

```
<h2>Transform</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("TransformedMessage", "Transformer", FormMethod.Post))
{    
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InputMessagePath, new { @type="file"}) <br /><br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedTransform, new SelectList(Model.TransformClassTypes), new { @id="lstTransforms", @name="lstTransforms"}) <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Transform"/> <br /><br /> 
}

@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.OutputMessage) <br /><br />
```

This happens with the render event when the output is written to the text area while the text box (browse) is cleared. I really appreciate if anyone can help me to avoid this problem. I don't want any form component to be cleared after the submission.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller do you set model.SelectedTransform back the default value? If not, you should (if I understand your question), otherwise the dropdown will retain the user selection,

As @rowan mentioned, the file input field only gets cleared because the browsers don't support a preset value in that (security issue)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Robert. Is there anyway to set the default value of dropdownlist by using DropDownListFor method, (just like we do it using DropDownList method)? I mean in the view. I don't want to change the model instance which is passed from the controller to the view. I just want to add an additional element to the list in the view without affecting it to the contents of the model.

Answer (score 0):

A file input control cannot be repopulated with a value after a form submit. The user must select a file again.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a "textbox and a browse button" or two separate controls. Its a SINGLE control having type attribute 'file'.

```
<input type="file" />
```

Different browsers may render it differently. Some browsers show as you said, some shows a 'choose file' button and so. Because of the standards, you can't maintain the file selection info in file input control after the page is posted. Much similar to password fields cannot maintain values across postbacks. This is HTML standard.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to clear the Text contents of your 'HTML Form' then use Jquery AJAX for doing the Kind Of operations on Server Side Like:

```
  $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:("Home/Save"),
            data:{data:'FormData'},
            Success:function(response){
               //Do the Further Process
            }
        })
```

and on Server side just do your Server Operation as:

```
public JsonResult Test(FormDatas Data )
    {
        //You Operations
        return Json(Result);
    }
```